# Collection to Iterable

Tags: java, collections, iterable

How can I get a `java.lang.Iterable` from a collection like a `Set` or a `List`?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `Iterator` instead of `Iterable`? A `List` implements the `Iterable` interface. An `Iterator` allows you to iterate through a `List`'s elements.

Comment: My interface is actually SortedSet

Answer (score 102, accepted):

A [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) ***is*** an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html).

So you can write:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a string");

    Iterable<String> iterable = list;
    for (String s : iterable) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that the OP asked about it, but the assignment to `Iterable` is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @nwinkler agreed with your comment.

Comment: @myborobudur : what was the issue you had with the generics ?

Answer (score 12):

It's not clear to me what you need, so:

this gets you an Iterator

```
SortedSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<String>();
Iterator<String> iterator = sortedSet.iterator();
```

Sets and Lists are Iterables, that's why you can do the following:

```
SortedSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<String>();
Iterable<String> iterable = (Iterable<String>)sortedSet;
```

Comment: The OP asks for `Iterable` not an `Iterator`

Answer (score 7):

`Iterable` is a super interface to `Collection`, so any class (such as `Set` or `List`) that implements `Collection` also implements `Iterable`.

Answer (score 2):

Both [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interfaces extend the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface, which itself extends the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Collection` extends `java.lang.Iterable`, you don't have to do anything, it already is an Iterable.

```
groovy:000> mylist = [1,2,3]
===> [1, 2, 3]
groovy:000> mylist.class
===> class java.util.ArrayList
groovy:000> mylist instanceof Iterable
===> true
groovy:000> def doStuffWithIterable(Iterable i) {
groovy:001>   def iterator = i.iterator()
groovy:002>   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
groovy:003>     println iterator.next()
groovy:004>   }
groovy:005> }
===> true
groovy:000> doStuffWithIterable(mylist)
1
2
3
===> null
```